# How can I output the chkconfig results to a file within a shell script?

Tags: centos, shell-scripting

When I run the following from the linux command line it works properly and populates the chkconfig.bak file correctly :

```
#chkconfig --list > chkconfig.bak
```

But when the command is run from a daily shell script the chkconfig.bak file comes out empty.

Any guesses why this would be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will probably need to use the full path to `chkconfig`

```
/sbin/chkconfig --list > chkconfig.bak
```

and you may want to put a full path on the output too.